# How to install Python package leargist (GIST image descriptor) using libfftw3 on WINDOWS 10?

Tags: python, fftw, descriptor, gist, pyfftw

I am having problem installing `leargist` package on `WINDOWS 10` computer as described on your webpage: https://pypi.org/project/pyleargist/ for extracting image feature using `GIST` descriptor.

Instruction says to install `libffw3` (http://www.fftw.org), which I do not understand how to install on `WINDOWS 10`. Seems it is mainly built for `UNIX/LINUX` system.

I will appreciate **step by step** installing instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what else to say but check the documentation:
http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html. These are the libraries for Debug/Release to link against and the according headers. The dlls need to be in some binary search path of the system and voila.

Comment: @ Kavesh Vahedipour, it will be really helpful if you could provide a step by step procedure for doing that. Perhaps with image uploads for each step. It will help a lot of people. Now, I am trying to figure out which file, libraries to choose, how to install them, what path, etc.